# Argument #1 is not an array - Yajra/Datatables Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, ajax, json, datatables, laravel-7

Tengo una vista en mi proyecto en la que necesito programar la carga, búsqueda y paginación de los registros del lado del servidor. Tengo claro que con DataTables exclusivamente desde el cliente solamente trabaja con los datos que el servidor devuelve a la vista.

Implementé la librería tal y como la documentación dice que debe hacerse. Ya he visto decenas de tutoriales y todos son prácticamente iguales, pero a ellos sí les funciona.

El Ajax que hace la solicitud en la vista es:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict"
    // Inicio de la DataTable
    var dataListView = $(".data-list-view").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ url('todos-los-pedidos') }}",
        "columns": [
            {data: 'Pedido'},
            {data: 'Cliente'},
            {data: 'Marca'}
        ]
    });
});
```

La acción la pongo directamente en la ruta (también lo intenté poniéndola en un método de *PedidoController*, fallando igual), y es:

```
Route::get('todos-los-pedidos', function() {
    
    return datatables()->eloquent(Pedido::query())->toJson();
    
});
```

Cuando cargo la página, inmediatamente recibo una alert de JS diciendo:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Exception Message:

array_intersect_key(): Argument #1 is not an array
```

**SIN EMBARGO**, cuando ya se han cargado tanto el DOM como el despliegue de la datatable, aparece lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

13.379 es la cantidad *exacta* de registros que hay en la tabla, lo que al menos me indica que el método

`datatables()->eloquent(Pedido::query())->toJson()`

sí está accediendo a la tabla. Pero no puedo terminar el trabajo.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Los nombres de las columnas en tu petición AJAX son exactamente los mismos nombres de las columnas que retorna tu servicio?

Comment: Sí Jonatan, exactos.